backup files in a kubernetes Persistent Volume in Kubernetes using Velero
I'm trying to understand what it takes to backup the content of a persistent volume when using Velero 1.15. The documentation is unclear. Is it supported out of the box when using a S3 compatible backup volume using AWS as provider? Previous versions demanded restic to be installed.
I have tried to backup this volume
    apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: db-backup-stage-pv
  labels:
    type: db-backup
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  capacity:
    storage: 250Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/xyz/data"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: db-backup-stage-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: db-backup

attached to a pod like this:
  volumeMounts:
  - name: xyz-importer-init-pv-volume
    mountPath: "/tmp/importer"

  volumes:
  - name: xyz-importer-init-pv-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: xyz-init-pv-volume-claim

When running the backup:
velero backup create xyz-db --selector type=db-backup -n backup

(selecting the pod with annotation)
I get a backup, but can't see that the files in the PV are backed up. And they are not restored when running the restore command:
velero restore create --from-backup xyz-db -n backup

I'm using seaweedFS as backup volume: https://github.com/seaweedfs/seaweedfs with s3 enabled.
I can see when inspecting the backup that the content of the Volume is not backed up.
